# Changing the height of SELECT with Uniform / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this problem where I want to change the height of some select-dropdown listboxes.

At the moment this is how they look like
http://i46.tinypic.com/2qstseo.gif

And I would like them to be taller and also close together. I don't know if this is possible wih Uniform, but here is my code nevertheless:

```
#uniform-resize span
{
    width:120px;
    height:60px;

}
```

This is one of the selects (they are quite large):

```
<select id="resize">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas? Obviously the height:60px; does not work.

Thank you very much for the support guys, let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What control are you using?  With an out of the box select, the height works except for in safari where you need to set the line-height:  http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/DBHN7/3/

Comment: After re-reading.  It looks like you are using Uniform controls.  Looking at the demo page, there is an image file with http://uniformjs.com/images/sprite.png that contains the look and feel of the control.  You'd probably have to customize the images and update the CSS to get a different height that contained the up and down arrows. It might be easier to look for a different gui layout that supports height or just roll your own.

Comment: Hmm... OK, thank you very much :)
What about having them close together? :/

Comment: That's probably a margin/padding issue, you will have to post more HTML and CSS for that.  Ideally a fiddle showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in `uniform.default.css` and change some parts, for example, this part:

```
div.selector select {
  min-width: 190px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
}
```

or you can try adding `!important`

```
#resize
{
    width:120px !important;
    height:60px !important;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Uniform.js is using this sprite: http://uniformjs.com/images/sprite.png so I doubt you can really change the height of the select element.

**EDIT**:
To change the width:

```
.selector span{width:auto !important}
.selector select{width:auto !important}
.selector{width:auto !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the sprite image or use another one altogether (using the same layout) and then you need to overwrite all related CSS parts of Uniform, namely those with positions for this sprite image and font declarations. Check out Uniform's other themes - it's all there.

Btw: To save you future headache do not use !important, but overwrite existing CSS rules cleanly. Do so in a CSS file loaded AFTER uniform.default.css and don't mess with Uniform's files directly!